# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'" after computer restart

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda3

Over the weekend Windows restarted my computer for updates. Now I can no longer run large amounts of code!

I'm running this segment of `jyupter` code in `VS Code`

```
from tensorflow import keras

normalizer = keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization(axis=-1)
normalizer.adapt(ImageData)

ImageDataNorm = normalizer(ImageData)

print("var: %.4f" % np.var(ImageDataNorm))
print("mean: %.4f" % np.mean(ImageDataNorm))
```

But get: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras`

I'm using the proper interpreter and `conda list` includes the entire `tensorflow` package.

This is not the first time I've had modules go missing after restarts. My last solution was a complete removal of Python and conda but that's not really a workable solution.

Any help is appreciated, thanks folks!

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment in Juptyer?

Answer (score 0):

A `ModuleNotFoundError:` is triggered when a package can't be found, or is not installed. As you have recently updated, I assume your window's installation of Python as automatically upgraded.

> I'm using the proper interpreter and **`conda list` includes the entire `tensorflow` package.**

I don't think `conda list` will show you the packages in your Python library which are being used by VS Code

You can check your Python installed packages by using `pip list` in terminal. If `tensorflow` is not there, try the methods below.

---

VS code will take it's modules from Python directly. You can install modules with:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

And Anaconda uses:

```
conda install tensorflow
```

> https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-install